# Bootstrap table breaking after ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax, bootstrap-5

[image: 1]

Here is my ajax call that updates two tables in my MVC project when they user clicks on a value using the select.

however on every other call it breaks the button functionality on the tables.

The button becomes unusable on every other call

[image: 2]

All scripts tags are in a layout file which get applied to the page. I have tried to reload them in this page but I just end up with duplicates or just break the page completely.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! If you would like to get an answer to your question quicker, please [do not paste code as images](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode), include it as a text paste instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure because there is not enough code here,
but it seems to me that when you get a response from ajax call, you replace the whole html body with jquery.
By doing this your JS event aren't bind anymore.

If you really need to replace the body then you should bind again js action you need after doing

> ```
> $("body").html(result);
> $("#whateverNeedEvent").addEventListener(...
> ```